# XSLT: call-template vs mode for execution flow

Tags: xml, xslt

Which is better practice to use for execution flow, call-template or modes?

data.xml

```
<Properties>
    <foo>me</foo>
    <bar>you</bar>
</Properties>
```

a.xsl

```
<xsl:include href="translations_nomodes.xml"
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:call-template name="a_display"/>
</xsl:template>
```

b.xsl

```
<xsl:include href="translations_nomodes.xml"
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:call-template name="b_display"/>
</xsl:template>
```

translations_nomodes.xsl

```
<xsl:template name="a_display">
    <!-- display option a -->
    ...
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="b_display">
    <!-- display option b -->
    ...
</xsl:template>
```

Or would using modes be a better practice

c.xsl

```
<xsl:include href="translations_modes.xml"
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="/Properties" mode="c_display"/>
</xsl:template>
```

d.xsl

```
<xsl:include href="translations_modes.xml"
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="/Properties" mode="d_display"/>
</xsl:template>
```

translations_modes.xsl

```
<xsl:template match="Properties" mode="c_display">
    <!-- display option c -->
    ...
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Properties" mode="d_display">
    <!-- display option d -->
    ...
</xsl:template>
```

Since "Properties" is the root node in my document and the apply-templates use literals for their mode values, using mode won't give me any added benefit and it's slightly more verbose.  However if the execution flow is dependent upon an element/attribute within the document itself and the modes were not literals but expressions, then I could see the need for the mode approach.

In fact, using modes as I am, with literal values, seems like a bad choice also because if down the road my logic changes and I need to use mode expressions to control execution flow, I've already 'used' the mode attribute.

Have I come to the correct conclusion or am I missing some important points?

Comment: @new-Thrall, @Alejandro: Something is missing in this question. What is really the problem? I don't understand. Modes are meaningful if you need to process the same node more than once and each time in a different way. Separate templates are used when there is different processing for differently-matched nodes. It isn't clear from the question, which case we have here.

Comment: @Dimitire Novatchev: I think you're right. I think I need to  rephrase the question.

Comment: @Dimitre Novatchev - I think you and Alejandro have mostly answered it for me. I think my question now is when does it make sense to use xsl:call-template instead of just using xsl:apply-templates with select and match?

Comment: @myself -  I guess you'd use xsl:call-template when you wanted to apply a template when the decision can't be based on the current node (or chilren nodes) but on some other factor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Little late for an answer to this.  One big difference between apply-templates and call-template is that in the later case, the called template inherits the current node (sometimes called the context node) of the caller.  Whereas with apply-template the select="expr" determines the context mode by generating a list of nodes and then iterating over them.

Using your examples, a.xsl and b.xsl both match "/".  When they call-template a_display and b_display in translations_nomodes.xsl, those templates inherit "/" as the context node.

In contrast, the templates in c.xsl and d.xsl apply-templates with select="/Properties".  Since there's only one "/Properties", it's the only node in the list to iterate over, and it becomes the context node that the XSLT processor looks for the best match for.  Thus, the templates in translations_modes.xsl will see "/Properties" as the context node.

So which is the better practice?  Depends on whether you want to continue processing with the current context node or select other nodes to start processing over.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

**Remember: XSLT (as any declarative language) binds an input with wellknown schema to an output with wellknown schema.**

There is no such thing as "general solution".

Looking your example, this are the facts:

- Your input source has a `Properties`
  root element.
- Your process logic doesn't rest in
  XSLT, but in your decision: to run
  one transformation or another.

So, why did you have a common stylesheet with separate logic, and two "entry point" stylesheets for each logic? This doesn't make sense.

Best practice would be to have two stylesheet.

Comment: why are there two 'entry point" style sheets?  The skinning framework that I am working within requires it.  Why is there a common stylesheet?  I didn't include it in my example but often times the skins share common processing logic before branching.  So your recommendation would be to remove the branching logic from the common stylesheet and just include the common stuff in each unique stylesheet?

Comment: @new Thrall: I'm telling you what I see. `translations_nomodes.xsl` and `translations_modes.xsl` are the common stylesheets with diferent process logic trough named templates or modes. `a.xsl` and `b.xsl` or `c.xsl` and `d.xsl` are just entry point. Maybe you really have some common rules, but that is no showed here. You are driving the process logic, not the processor.